# AutoCAD viewer solution for sharepoint 2010

Tags: third-party-software, integration

What solutions are available that leverage SharePoint 2010 for:

1. Viewing drawings in web interface
2. Searching (iFilter) drawings
3. AutoCAD client integration (edit/open in AutoCAD)

Comment: What kind of solution?

Comment: autocad viewer . I know bamboo has one but it is like 6 grand

Comment: Please make your questions more specific

Answer (score 2):

MetaData Extractor for pulling drawing data in to SharePoint libraries.
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-dwg-parser-solution-accelerator.aspx

AutoCAD plugin for working with SharePoint from the client (free)
http://www.bentley.com/en-US/Products/ProjectWise+StartPoint/AutoCAD-plugin.htm

A full drawing management system build on SharePoint
http://www.cadac.com/organice/Pages/default.aspx